# How to install and configure IPython so it uses Python3.2 on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, software-installation, python, configuration

How to install and configure IPython so it uses Python3.2 on 11.10?  I've checked that by installing

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

will use `python2.7`.

### [EDIT1]

```
$ sudo python3 configure.py
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.8.5 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 3.2.2 on linux2.

Type '2' to view the GPL v2 license.
Type '3' to view the GPL v3 license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
Found the license file pyqt-gpl.sip.
Checking to see if the QtGui module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtHelp module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtMultimedia module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtNetwork module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDeclarative module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtOpenGL module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScript module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtScriptTools module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSql module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtSvg module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtTest module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtWebKit module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXml module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtXmlPatterns module should be built...
Checking to see if the phonon module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtAssistant module should be built...
Checking to see if the QtDesigner module should be built...
Checking to see if the dbus support module should be built...
DBus v1 does not seem to be installed.
Qt v4.7.4 free edition is being used.
SIP 4.12.4 is being used.
The Qt header files are in /usr/include/qt4.
The shared Qt libraries are in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.
The Qt binaries are in /usr/bin.
The Qt mkspecs directory is in /usr/share/qt4.
These PyQt modules will be built: QtCore, QtHelp, QtNetwork, QtDeclarative,
QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtSvg, QtTest, QtWebKit, QtXml, QtXmlPatterns,
QtDesigner.
The PyQt Python package will be installed in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
PyQt is being built with generated docstrings.
PyQt is being built with 'protected' redefined as 'public'.
The Designer plugin will be installed in
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/designer.
The PyQt .sip files will be installed in /usr/share/sip/PyQt4.
pyuic4, pyrcc4 and pylupdate4 will be installed in /usr/bin.
Generating the C++ source for the QtCore module...
sh: /usr/bin/sip: not found
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
$ which sip
$ sudo apt-get install sip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sip
$
```

Comment: do you mean 11.10

Comment: Yes. Corrected in title.

Comment: but not in body.. :P

Comment: It is fixed now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `pip3` to install ipython.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install ipython
```

Comment: `pip3` doesn't give me a `ipython3` command. I put `python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/IPython/__main__.py` in `/usr/local/bin/ipython3` myself to handle that.

Comment: How to install pip3?

Comment: That yields `E: Unable to locate package pip3`.

Comment: The correct command is `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: For me, it appears that these commands make `ipython` default to Python 3, whereas it was Python 2 previously. Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [python-sip-dev [image: Install python-sip-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-sip-dev) or `/usr/bin/sip` will not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Julian Taylor has PPAs for IPython:

[IPython stable](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython) (ppa:jtaylor/ipython)

[IPython nightlies](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython-dev) (ppa:jtaylor/ipython-dev)

For oneiric, installing `ipython3` from either of those gets you the standard terminal IPython. The Qt console and the HTML notebook both work in Python 3, but you'll need to install some dependencies. There are [instructions on the IPython wiki](http://wiki.ipython.org/Python_3).

Comment: Following instructions at [here](http://wiki.ipython.org/Python_3), I get `$ python3 configure.py
python3: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` Where is this `configure.py`?

Comment: @user6076: When you do `apt-get source python-qt4`, it will create a directory python-qt4-..., which you need to `cd` into. I've updated the wiki to clarify this.

Comment: Still not working because of `sip` not found, see in the original post.

Comment: @user6076: Have you installed `python3-sip-dev`? It's possible you also need `python-sip-dev`, I haven't tried without it.